Does $|G:H \cap K|$ divide $|G:H| |G:K|$?
I have encountered this problem, and I am very stuck.
Let $H$ and $K$ be subgroups of finite index in $G$, possibly infinite. Prove that $|G:H \cap K|$ divides $|G:H| |G:K|$.
My first thought was to use the fact $|HK| = \frac{|H| |K|}{|H \cap K|}$ when $H$ and $K$ are finite, but the problem highlights that $H$ and $K$ have finite indices, which does not imply that $H$ and $K$ are finite. At this point, I am unsure of how to continue. How should I proceed?

Mod out by the core of $H\cap K$ to drop into the finite case. Note that $H\cap K$ is of finite index, so it contains a normal subgroup of finite index.

If $A \leq B \leq G$, $|G:A| = |G:B|,|B:A|$.

Didn't you ask this already here? We have $$[G:H∩K]=[G:H][H:H∩K]$$ by the tower law of subgroups.

@DietrichBurde It's not the same person who asked it.

I think the statement in the question is not true. Consider $G=S_3$, $H={(1,2), id}$, $K={(2,3), id}$ then $|G:H|=|G:K|=3$, $|G:H\cap K|=6$. But $6\nmid 9$.

@DietrichBurde The duplicate shows that $[G:K\cap H]\leq [G:K][G:H]$ and is divisible by $\mathrm{lcm}([G:K][G:H])$. This asks to prove that it divides $[G:K][G:H]$.

While it is true that $\mathrm{lcm}([G:H],[G:K])$ divides $[G:H\cap K]$, and that $[G:H\cap K]\leq [G:H][G:K]$, it is not generally true that $[G:H\cap K]$ divides $[G:H][G:K]$. This can fail even for finite groups, as noted in comments.
For example, @Nothing special notes that if $G=S_3$ and $H$ and $K$ are distinct subgroups of order $2$, then $[G:H]=[G:K]=3$, but $[G:H\cap K] = |G| = 6$. And $6$ does not divide $9$. More generally, if $G$ is a group of order $p^ak$ with $\gcd(p,k)=1$, $k\gt 1$, and $G$ has two distinct Sylow $p$-subgroups $H$ and $K$, then $[G:H][G:K]=k^2$, but $[G:H\cap K]$ is divisible by $p$, hence cannot divide $k^2$.

Should the title of the question be changed? It may be misleading if it pops up on a Google search.

@Nothingspecial Perhaps the title has a typo, too? That is meant "is divisible by"? Because this version is just not true.

@DietrichBurde That's also not true. Maybe we just need to change it into a question.

This has all helped me tremendously, thank you all for the clarification!

@DietrichBurde Yes, but the product need not divide $[G:H\cap K]$. So not so much a typo as both a missing comma and changing "divides" to "is divisible by"....

Or a misunderstanding that $a\mid n$ and $b\mid n$ doesn't mean $ab\mid n$, but only $lcm(a,b)\mid n$. And the "correct" version was indeed intended.
